# Setting splitContainer property sizes depending on Form size C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I am having trouble setting `splitContainer` sizes depending on my Form size.

When my form is loaded it is at a `MinimumSize` of `1170,930`. But if I resize my form both `.SplitterDistance` and `.Panel2MinSize` are at different places then where they should be.

I have tried the following using the `Form_SizeChanged` event but it is not working correctly. Is there a way I can calculate `.SplitterDistance` and `.Panel2MinSize` to cater for the form resize.

```
private void MainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = this.Size.Height;         
    int y = this.MinimumSize.Height;   

    splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance + (x - y);
    splitContainer1.Panel2MinSize = splitContainer1.Panel2MinSize + (x - y);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Added some pics to give a better example below.

**Form Standard** (what it should look like)

[image]

**Form Resized**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep one of the Panels the same size, moving the splitter as the Form is resized.

There's a property to tell it whether the first or second Panel should remain "fixed" when resizing:

```
splitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel2;  // or FixedPanel.Panel1
```

Comment: I knew there was `.IsSplitterFixed` property, but didnt know about `.FixedPanel`.. Thanks!